# How to display the highest value in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have these two values in a post in WordPress, each of them returns an area:

```
<?php listingpress_property_area(); ?>
<?php listingpress_property_areautil(); ?>
```

and I only need to show the highest; is it possible?

The above functions return values such as 200 and 600 or 400 and 300 and I need something that takes the two values and returns only the highest.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? what values you are getting?

Comment: What values are they returning now? Just provide some sample data.

Comment: The functions listed above are going to output values. The first thing you need to do is find the equivalent function(s) for returning instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get output to variables. This is solved by ob_start() and ob_get_clean(), which put all output to buffer instead of the screen and return buffer to a variable. Then compare two variables and echo the highest:

```
ob_start();
listingpress_property_area();
$a = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
listingpress_property_areautil();
$b = ob_get_clean();

echo max($a, $b);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, opens some paths, but for whatever reason it returns the two values

Comment: I apologize, it was a mistake. I have edited the answer.